# Is it possible to define an acronym-command which behaves differently on the first invocation than on the rest?

Tags: macros, conditionals, acronyms

Most technical writers will immediately see how I'd like to use this. I'm writing a paper about something I'll call *That Which Will Be Abbreviated (TWWBA)*. I'd like to have a macro, `\TWWBA{}`, that will produce `That Which Will Be Abbreviated (TWWBA)` the first time it is called, and `TWWBA` on all following invocations.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd actually like to see a general solution to the problem. Presumably it would be a macro that would be defined to redefine itself on its first usage?

Comment: @Seamus: Either that or a macro that changes a flag on first use that tells it to use the other text on the following uses. I slightly changed the title of this question to make it acronym-specific, hoping that users who don't know `glossaries` or `acronym` would get help here. I'd recommend looking for a general solution in another question? Just to keep the purposes separate -- acronyms vs. general usage.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great response and the edits. I'm all set in terms of the article I'm writing, but another answer that explained how this could be done with conditionals would be great, if only for completeness.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I recommend using **glossaries** or **acronym** (with a preference for the former). For limited use one can also define them directly:

```
\newcommand{\newacronym}[3]{\newcommand#1{#3 (#2)\gdef#1{#2}}}
```

Thus

```
\newacronym{\TWWBA}{TWWBA}{That Which Will Be Abbreviated}
```

will allow to write `\TWBBA` and get

> That Which Will Be Abbreviated (TWWBA)

the first time and

> TWWBA

thereafter. This is roughly what the two packages do (but they do better): the first execution of the command redefines itself. It's necessary to use low level commands, because the higher level LaTeX commands are unable to make global definitions of commands.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it answers the question exactly as I asked it as well as pointing me to *acronym* and *glossary*, which are both excellent.

Comment: @ColinK You shouldn't.

Comment: Why not? It includes the basics of the other answers, and tells me what I wanted to know about writing macros.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer, so it gets my vote!

Answer (score 17):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newacronym{twwba}{TWWBA}{That Which Will Be Abbreviated}
\begin{document}
text \gls{twwba}


more text \gls{twwba} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is handled nicely by the `acronym` package. I recommend it.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by egreg in the comment below, the `glossaries` package is particularly useful for this too.

Comment: Also the **glossaries** package has this feature and is more customizable.

Comment: Indeed it does. I used that one for my thesis and was very pleased with the result.